# Custom view and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, custom-view

I created a custom view (the title of my app) in order to apply a font ttf. The problem is when the device goes into landscape mode and tabs go to actionbar, my title is shrinking.

Anyone know a solution?

Screenshots:

**normal**

[image]

**Landscape**
[image]